# Why is my alchemy lab making the wrong potions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, so I have been having issues with my alchemy lab in the game Skyrim.  I am trying to make potions of restore health, but it is making fortify health instead.  I am using wheat and blue mountain flowers, which should have both effects, restore and fortify, and i'm under the restore health tab.  Why does it keep doing this?

Comment: is it changing after you brew it or does the preview of your potion match the outcome ?

Comment: the preview matches the outcome

Comment: according to a few alchemy lab applications the potion is named **fortify health**, but it also does both: restore heath by X and health increased by Y depening on your alchemy level + buffs

Comment: hold up... what's with the x and y stuff?  You have just confused me even more...

Comment: X and Y are just variables as these values increase depending on your alchemy level.  The base values of X and Y in this case are 22 and 17

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The potion you are creating is named **Fortify Health** but it should have both **Restore Health** by X and **Health increased** by Y for 60 seconds

X & Y values depend on your alchemy level and/or buffs you have on at the time your create the potion.

See below [as pulled](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Wheat_(Skyrim)) from the [Skyrim Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blue_Mountain_Flower):

[image]

Both ingredients have Restore Health and Fortify Health as their traits.

Example: Alchemy skill of level 15 without any fortify alchemy should make you a Potion of Fortify Health with the following values:

- Health increased by 17 points for 60 seconds
- Restore 22 points of Health

The higher level alchemy skill + any Fortify alchemy buff will increase both 'health increased by' values and how much health is restored. There are plenty of Alchemy lab web applications out there, but here are a few: [Alchemy Lab](http://www.garralab.com/skyrim/alchemy.php), [Alchemy Calculator](https://arrington.me/alch/), [Recipes Finder,](http://rp.eliteskills.com/skyrim.html) etc

I also just fired up my Skyrim to verify this.  Here is a screenshot of crafting that potion.  See that is is named Fortity Health, but the potion does restore health as well (given the traits of both ingredients). At the time of this brew, my current Alchemy level is 47, no alchemy buffs, and I have not spent any skills in the Alchemy skill tree.

[image]

Last - if you are looking to create a potion of **JUST** restore health, use the following ingredients:

- blue dartwing + butterfly wing
- blue dartwing + charred skeever hide
- blisterwort + butterfly wing
- blue dartwing + eye of sabre cat
- blue dartwing + imp stool
- blue dartwing + rock warbler egg
- blisterwort + charred skeever hide
- blue dartwing + wheat
- blue mountain flower + butterfly wing
- blue mountain flower + charred skeever hide
- blue mountain flower + daedra heart
- blue mountain flower + eye of sabre cat
- blue mountain flower + imp stool
- blue mountain flower + rock warbler egg
- blue mountain flower + swamp fungal pod
- blisterwort + daedra heart
- blisterwort + blue mountain flower
- blisterwort + eye of sabre cat
- blisterwort + imp stool
- butterfly wing + imp stool
- butterfly wing + rock warbler egg
- butterfly wing + swamp fungal pod
- butterfly wing + wheat
- charred skeever hide + daedra heart
- blisterwort+ blue dartwing
- charred skeever hide + imp stool
- charred skeever hide + rock warbler egg
- charred skeever hide + swamp fungal pod
- charred skeever hide + wheat
- blisterwort + swamp fungal pod
- daedra heart + imp stool
- daedra heart + rock warbler egg
- daedra heart + swamp fungal pod
- blisterwort + wheat
- eye of sabre cat + imp stool
- eye of sabre cat + rock warbler egg
- eye of sabre cat + swamp fungal pod
- eye of sabre cat + wheat
- imp stool + rock warbler egg
- blue dartwing + blue mountain flower
- imp stool + wheat
- rock warbler egg + swamp fungal pod
- rock warbler egg + wheat
- butterfly wing + charred skeever hide

Comment: Wow... You went to a lot of trouble to answer this question...

Comment: I am on a Skyrim kick lately so I dont mind.

Comment: The pictures of the ingredients... did you get those from The Elder Scrolls Wiki on Fandom?

Comment: Yes, links to each of them are above the pictures

Comment: so do you actually use Fandom a lot?  I use it all the time to figure stuff out that I need to know right away and can't post here and wait for an answer!

Comment: See additional edit if it helps you  and yes I use that wiki often + searching on here (gaming.stackexchange.com) as this game has been out for a while now. There are a lot of questions and wonderful answers on here